# How do I add UIAlertView to my completeTransaction method

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uialertview

I would like a really simple way to add a UIAlertView once the user has completed a (consumable) IAP. Right now I have a method that shows me in the output that the transaction is complete. Additionally the "coins" they have purchased are added to their total coins. I am wondering if there is some simple code I can add in to the completeTransaction method to display a UIAlertView that simply informs them that their transaction is complete and then a "dismiss" button. I have included my completeTransaction method below and the provideContent method I am using in case that's where the code should go. If this is not the way to go please let me know what would be better. I am very new to this so simple step by step answers are what I can usually follow. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
NSLog(@"completeTransaction...");

[self provideContentForProductIdentifier:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
}

- (void)provideContentForProductIdentifier:(NSString *)productIdentifier {

//Product 1
if ([productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"POC1"]) {
     // unlock product 1
    unsigned long long currentCoins = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"coins"] unsignedLongLongValue];
    unsigned long long newTotalCoins = currentCoins + 500;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLong:newTotalCoins] forKey:@"coins"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

} else {
    [_purchasedProductIdentifiers addObject:productIdentifier];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:productIdentifier];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 postNotificationName:IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification
 object:productIdentifier userInfo:nil];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the transaction is finished, put this code(if it's successful0

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" message:@"Transaction complete" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
```

Comment: Wow that was quick and easy and worked perfectly! Thank You!!!!! Says I can't check the answer off for 6 minutes but I will then!

Comment: BTW I put the code in the provideConentForProductIdentifier between the if and else so that it would only display once the particular product has been delivered.